# Storing multiple values in a column

Tags: sql, sqlplus

SQL question - how can I create a column that would store two values like this one:

```
EFFECTIVE RANGE
200 - 300
```

... and so on. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are the 2 values? `Effective Range` and `200 - 300`? `200` and `300` and the column name is `Effective Range`? I wouldn't store more than 1 value in a column. I would make a second column and put the additional data there.

Comment: JUST DON'T! This will only cost you trouble. Use separate columns

Comment: The column is EFFECTIVE RANGE and we want to store two values 200, 300 separated by '-'.

Comment: No, this is an anti-pattern, a columns should store a single atomic piece of data; you need two columns, a lower_bound and upper_bound

Comment: This implies that you really don't want to use the database for what it is designed for, but consume the data elsewhere. If so, consider keeping them in a JSON or XML datatype (at least they will have some structure than simple strings.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on your reasons for taking this design path?

Comment: `200` and `300` represent different concepts. One is the low bound of a range, and the other one is the upper bound of it. You should use two columns. Alternatively, you can create a `range` "structure type" in Oracle, and then store it as a unit.

Comment: You 're right, it's not best practice. I think I will follow the low bound - upper bound split. Thanks for your help!